# What's 'imminent death' in German?

Tags: translation

Example: Leading to imminent death

Comment: Please see the above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Imminent Death = unmittelbar bevorstehender Tod

Comment: Das wäre eine mehr oder weniger wörtliche Übersetzung. Doch sie ist wenig alltagstauglich, denn man würde es in realen Situationen so nicht sagen. Siehe des Fragestellers (minimalistischer) Beispielsatz *leading to imminent death*. Auch  hier kommt es wieder darauf an, wie die Kontext-Situation ist (die Frage verrät hier zu wenig). Plausibel wäre z.B. in einem Gespräch über die Wirkung von Toxinen: *Ein Tropfen davon führt unmittelbar zum Tod.*